# Prevent a user from closing or uninstalling application until he provides some password entry

Tags: security

In our company we're looking for a way to prevent users from closing certain applications or uninstalling them unless they provide a password.
we googled a lot on this issue but didn't find anything and 
it seems Active Direcory does not provide this kind of feature (we may mistaken... ).

Can someone point me to a solution ?

Thanx

Comment: What operating system (Windows, Linux, OS X) are your users running?

Comment: Hi, thanx for your reply. The users run windows 7 or 8. The server is running windows 2003 server.

Comment: Ok.  Windows users cannot install or uninstall an application unless they have administrator privileges.  Windows users cannot stop a Windows service running with administrator privileges.  Do your users have administrator accounts?

Comment: The users open sesions and connect through the local network to their computers.